# Объем данных в канале

Tags: c, linux

Нужно открыть канал, выделить буфер, считать данные, закрыть канал. Обычный подход на основе ftell, fseek с каналом не работает: функции возвращают ошибку.

Как узнать объем данных, которые есть в канале (pipe)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем случае, единственный надежный переносимый способ узнать сколько данных в канале - это считать эти данные из канала.

Можно читать частями, в заранее выделенный небольшой буфер. Сколько реально будет считано, столько и есть данных в канале. Если памяти будет не хватать, то довыделять по необходимости.

Comment: В некоторых случаях можно узнать сколько данных можно получить без блокировки.. например, для сокетов можно узнать. Но, cool, правда ваша: надёжного и _переносимого_ способа нет. Да и очень часто не нужно знать.